# Run an Action in change of DropDownListFor with pass parameters in ASP.NET MVC3 with Razor View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu, onchange

I am interesting to run an Action in change of DropDown. At now I don't want to use any Ajax or javascripts, I need postback.
This is my Edit View Code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Title, MySelectList)
```

And my html dom:

```
<select name="Title" id="Title">
    <option value="7" selected="selected">AV</option>
    <option value="9">HS</option>
    <option value="8">IT</option>
</select>
```

so I need in change of dropdown run `MajorCategoryChange` Action with the parameters of
`PPId = Model.Id` and `CategoryId = selectedoption.Value`  attention that DropDown is in Edit View Action and in change I need another action run it.

The returned Url is like this:

```
"http://MyProject/Products/ProductPoint/MajorCategoryChange?PPId=1&CategoryId=123"
```

What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You have to put some JavaScript code in the `onchange`-attribute, not just an URL. If you want to redirect the user to another page, you can use `location.href`.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Title, MySelectList, new { @onchange = "location.href = http://MyProject/Products/ProductPoint/MajorCategoryChange?PPId=1&CategoryId=123;" })
```

Comment: I use the exact code of you said, nothing change yet, steel the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, as you say you want to use `onchange` but also that you don't want to use javascript.  `onchange` will only work with javascript.  If you don't want to use javascript, you'll have to wrap the select in a form and have a submit button to get your postback.

e.g.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MajorCategoryChange", "YourController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="PPId" value="@Model.Id" />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Title, MySelectList)
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
}
```

As you have it set up the value that you want for your CategoryId will come in through model binding with the name `Title`, so you may want to change the parameter name on your model from `Title` to `CategoryId`.  Or change your parameter names in your action method, e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MajorCategoryChange(int PPId, int Title)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer actually I need an implementation to run an Action in DropDown Changed, not with other button (as you said submit button)

Comment: Then try adding @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.Title, MySelectList, new { @onchange = "this.form.submit()" }) .

Comment: Assume dropdownfor is in Edit View And I need to run MajorCategoryChange  Action in change of it, if I use your suggestion code just Edit Action run again or Edit action of httppost

Comment: What does your form tag look like?

Comment: what you mean of form tag? I use ` @using(Html.BeginForm()) { ...`

Comment: Try using the Html.BeginForm as I put in my answer.  If you call it as you posted, with no arguments, it will call again the same action that your url currently refers to.  So you need to explicitly point it to the action you want, as in the code in my answer.